# How to specify pivot table for hasOne() relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a couple of models that I have included pivot tables for to avoid a polymorphic relation.

```
role table
id
name
description

restriction table
id
rule
status

restriction_role table
id
restriction_id
role_id
```

Reason for this setup is that both Roles and Restrictions can actually belong to multiple other models. In this case, a Role can only have 1 Restriction. I would normally define this as

```
class Role extends Eloquent {
    public function restrictions()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Restriction');
    }
}
```

This obviously does not work because Laravel is unaware of the pivot table connecting this relation. I could easily accomplish this by using a many-to-many relationship instead, but this is not exactly how my model works. Not seeing anything in the documentation for defining this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why can't you just add `restriction_id` to the table `role`?

Comment: Also, just as a convention, your method should be called `restriction()` (singular), since it is returning only one restriction

Comment: Perhaps using the hasManyThrough() or belongsToMany() relationshipa, even though it's only to one entry

Comment: I guess I could add restriction_id to role, but a role is not required to have a restriction

Comment: Also, that is typically the inverse of how a one-to-one relationship is defined no? Laravel will query the restrictions table to look for role_id, which would not be found.

Comment: @MarkBaker I could use belongsToMany. This would work fine. Since there is only 1 restriction however, I was attempting to use hasOne()

Comment: Only `belongsToMany` will work here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @deczo stated in the comments, belongsToMany() is about all that will work here. I recommend returning the first result using the `first()` method if you require only one result but cannot use a `hasOne()` relationship.

Answer (score 10):

I've solved this by using the `belongsToMany` relation and defining a custom accessor for it, like so:

```
public function foo()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Bar::class);
}

public function getFooAttribute()
{
    return $this->foo()->first();
}
```